# How can I insert Variable into variable name which is imported from other file?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to put variables(in loop) to call const name, which I imported from other file.

I want to import const from file like this:

```
export const p6_q1="AAA";
export const p6_q2="BBB";
export const p6_q3="CCC";
export const p6_q4="DDD";
```

I've tried this :

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Text from 'textKorean';

const FaqItem = ({obj}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(obj)}
            { Text.p6_q`${String(obj)}` }
        </div>
    );
};

export default FaqItem;
```

props 'obj' is well presented on my console.
But the error message says:

> ./src/FaqItem.js
>       Attempted import error: 'p6_q' is not exported from 'textKorean' (imported as 'Text').

I want it to be p6_q1. p6_q2, p6_q3, ... and so on.

but my code in
`` { Text.p6_q`${String(obj)}` } `` says it is just
`p6_q`.

How can I do that?

Comment: so easy... { Text[`p6_q${String(obj)}`] } (there are back ticks after the open bracket and before the close bracket)

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo It shows me error that requires ']' after p6_q

Comment: what is the result of `{console.log(obj)}`

Comment: @JSEngine it shows 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. the original List which call this Item component is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: could you again use ``{ Text[`p6_q${String(obj)}`] } ``

Comment: @JSEngine It works!!! Thank you very much. How can I call it by [], even though Text is not an array?????

Comment: yeah Text is not array. we can access object properties with `.` dot notation i.e `obj.properties`. or  bracket notation `[]` i.e `obj['properties']`. we have used `[]` bracket notation  to access object properties. for more detail go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: didn't know that! Thank you for your reply and edit, genius :)

Comment: @심시은 whenever you want access object properties dynamically i.e using variable. Use `[]` bracket notation. eg: `obj[somevariable]` or ``Text[`p6_q${String(obj)}`]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should probably change the import to `import * as Text from './textKorean.js'`, if the textKorean file is in the same folder as your FaqItem. 
Next, is your `obj` is an array, you'll have to map the array. You should try

```
{ obj.map(num => Text["p6_q"+num])}
```